# Juypter Notebook on Python Version and PIP on Window 10 (64 bit)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pip, kernel

I used to run Python 3.8.2 on Window 10 (64 bit) and I am able to view all the modules that I have installed from the Window Command line 'pip list command'.

Recently, I installed Python 3.12.1. However, my Jupyter Notebook is loading from Python 3.8.2. I tried to view my modules and the old list of modules seemed to be 'gone' (I suspect the list only display the current python version module ?)

Can someone help me:

1. How do I load my Jupyter Notebook from my new python 3.12.1 ?
2. How do I view my modules that were installed under old python 3.8.2 ?

Thanks.